# Light client support for Stellar Core

Tags: stellar-core

Is there a [light client](https://www.parity.io/what-is-a-light-client/) already? If not does Stellar core support proofs to verify that a TX was executed and data persisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not support this at this point as it was not voted by the community.

For more paranoid clients, the easiest thing to do is to query multiple public Horizon nodes from different organizations and compare responses (that should match).